# MySQL - Randomly long DESCRIBE queries

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have several queries like this (running on MySQL 5.5):

```
DESCRIBE `TABLE`;
```

And it randomly takes 5-10 seconds on my production servers. We have an ORM that caches this data once per day (per web server) and I'm wondering why I see these slow queries popping up from time to time. I'm thinking that I could just change the web servers to cache until their processes are restarted but it'd be nice to know if there's an easy fix or something I could look into that may be causing this.

Comment: Retrieving from Information schema can be slow when there are a lot of databases and tables.

Comment: See this blog post and the solution it offers: [MySQL Performance Blog: Solving INFORMATION_SCHEMA slowness](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/)